# Post Json Data with key and values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am posting a JSON data with url and it's parameters. The problem is, when i post it in Postman i gets `"status": "Success","msg": "You Membership Form Submitted SuccessFully"`, but when I post it in my Xcode 7.2.1 then it gives `"status":"Failed","msg":"You Membership Form did not Submit SuccessFully"`. So please suggest me how to solve it.

The way i am doing is as follows :-

```
NSURL *baseUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrlStringForMembershipPageToSubmitdata];

NSDictionary *mapData=@{@"field_name_value":@{@"_levelOfMembershipTableView":@"menu-291"},@{@"_upgradeMembershipTableView":@"menu-565"},@{@"_detailsTableView":@"menu-696"},@{@"_txtFirstNameMembership.text":@"text-708"},@{@"_txtLastNameMembership.text":@"text-274"},@{@"_txtDOBMembership.text":@"text-443"},@{@"_txtCompanyNameMembership.text":@"text-970"},@{@"_txtJobTitleMembership.text":@"text-961"},@{@"_txtAddressMembership.text":@"text-785"},@{@"_txtCityMembership.text":@"text-482"},@{@"_txtPostCodeMembership.text":@"text-760"},@{@"_countryTableView":@"menu-19"},@{@"_txtEmailMembership.text":@"text-577"},@{@"_txtHomePhoneMembership.text":@"text-760"},@{@"_txtMobilePhoneMembership.text":@"text-394"},@{@"_txtWorkPhoneMembership.text":@"text-914"},@{@"_contactByTableView":@"menu-373"},@{@"_interestedInTableView":@"menu-527"},@{@"_hearAboutUsTableView":@"menu-997"} };

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager=[AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:baseUrlStringForMembershipPageToSubmitdata parameters:mapData constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
 {
 }
     progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
 }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Errorrrrrrr=%@",error.localizedDescription);
     UIAlertController *alertValidator2=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Please fill correctly" message:@"!!!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
     UIAlertAction *alertaction2=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {}];
     [alertValidator2 addAction:alertaction2];
     [self presentViewController:alertValidator2 animated:YES completion:nil];
 }];
```

I am sending "field_name_value" as key. The parameters I am sending on postman are :-

Key - field_name_value Value -

```
[
    {
        "field_value": "_levelOfMembershipTableView",
        "field_name": "menu-291"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_upgradeMembershipTableView",
        "field_name": "menu-565"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_detailsTableView",
        "field_name": "menu-696"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtFirstNameMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-708"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtLastNameMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-274"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtDOBMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-443"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtCompanyNameMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-970"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtJobTitleMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-961"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtAddressMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-785"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtCityMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-482"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtPostCodeMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-760"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_countryTableView",
        "field_name": "menu-19"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtEmailMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-577"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtHomePhoneMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-760"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtMobilePhoneMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-394"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_txtWorkPhoneMembership.text",
        "field_name": "text-914"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_contactByTableView",
        "field_name": "menu-373"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_interestedInTableView",
        "field_name": "menu-527"
    },
    {
        "field_value": "_hearAboutUsTableView",
        "field_name": "menu-997"
    }
]
```

Comment: Sorry I am using Xcode 8.1

Comment: try without  `manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];`

Comment: When I am posting data like these parameters, its shows 1 error.

Comment: Please update question with the error code and description.